# How do you validate password fields in serializers and save them to database with user?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am setting up a Django rest API for accessing my bank account system.
my models serialize well into JSON format except that I dont know how to handle passwords the same way we do with forms. Kindly help. Below are my relevant files.

I have tried defining password fields in serializers.py but when I run the project, it tells me the custom User instance has no attribute 'password1' which I understand is true because AbstractUser has no attributes named password1 and password2.

accounts/models.py:

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    contact_no = models.IntegerField(unique=False, null=True, blank=True)
    account_no = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        unique=True,
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(1000000000),
            MaxValueValidator(9999999999)
        ])
    balance = models.DecimalField(
        default=0,
        max_digits=12,
        decimal_places=2


    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', ]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.full_name)

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

api/serializers.py:

```
class UserSerializer(RegisterSerializer):
    password1 = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        style={'input_type': 'password', 'placeholder': 'Password'}
    )
    password2 = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        style={'input_type': 'password', 'placeholder': 'Confirm Password'}
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'contact_no',
            'password1',
            'password2',
        ]
```

api/views.py:

```
from rest_framework import generics

from accounts.models import User

from .serializers import UserSerializer


class UserCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
```

Comment: I think you don't need to serialize your user models to handle authentication. did you check on documentation ?? https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#basicauthentication

Comment: i want to register users

Comment: Did checked this https://wsvincent.com/django-rest-framework-user-authentication-tutorial/ ?

Comment: Yes I checked it @Umair. The difference is that I want to authenticate using Account Number and password

Comment: my question is how do u extend the registration part to add extra fields

Comment: You can expose `account_number` instead of `email/username` field ?

Comment: what is RegisterSerilizer parent class will do ?

Comment: override create method in model serializer and create user and set_password using password1 or password2